# Unable to hide divs on selection

Tags: jquery, html, input

I'm adding dynamically `div`s based on input user.

The problem is that the `div` "Add new users", instead of reducing `div`s (when i'm reducing the number of the `input`) it is adding `div`s. See the code please
https://jsfiddle.net/alessiow/n9xskt28/81/

```js
$(function() {
  $(".instancesN").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".instancesNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($("div.instancesNSpecifics").html());
      $(".instancesNContainer").prepend(block);
    }
  });



  $(".instancesNContainer").on('change', '.usersvmaddnewdivsN', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
    }
    $(this).parent().append($("div.usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").append(block);

  });

  $("div.instancesNSpecifics").on('change', '.usersvmaddnewdivsN', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
    }
    $(this).parent().append($("div.usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").append(block);


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='1');" value="1" name='instancesN[]' placeholder="Instances #" class="instancesN form-control" />
<div class="instancesNContainer"></div>
<div class='instancesNSpecifics'>
  <input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" name='usersvmaddnewdivsN[]' placeholder="Add new Users" class="form-control usersvmaddnewdivsN" />
  <div class="usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer"></div>
  <div class='usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics'>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control usernamevmN" name='usernamevmN[]' placeholder="VM-Username" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You only need one `$(function() {` and your HTML is invalid. Please complete it

Comment: I saw, but why remove the snippet. It is SO useful to not have to go to JSFiddle - I have recreated the snippet  and pressed TIDY!

Comment: The code seems to do what you want. If I type 3 I get 3 if I type 2 I get 2

Comment: @mplungjan if you try to decrement, it does not! I don't know...

Comment: @mplungjan check the "Add new Users" div

Comment: You're calling `.empty()` on `.usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer` but you're not actually appending anything to that `<div>` to begin with. Look at where your new users are being appended in the inspector tools.

Comment: @user7290573 how?